# How to handle special cases in my Python code?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have the following Python homework:

[image: Homework Requirement]

This is what the file looks like:

[image: This is what the file looks like]

I have been asked to handle some special cases in my calculations. For example, when I had something like 25/0 it will become an error. How can I do that?

This is my current code:

```
import os.path
fLocation="//Users//Ivan//Desktop//"
print("Assumed file location is at: ", fLocation)
fName = input("\nPlease enter a file name with its extension (ex. XXX.txt): ")

fin = open(fLocation + fName, 'r')

fLinesList=fin.readlines()

fin.close()
print('*' * 50, "\nData items have been read from file:\n\t"
                         + fLocation + fName + '\n')

print('-' * 30, "\nThe list of the lines in the file:\n", fLinesList)

print("\nThere are", len(fLinesList), "lines\n")

          # Print file content line by line
print('\n' + '-' * 30 + '\nFile "' + fName + '" contains:\n')
print(fLinesList[0].strip())
print(fLinesList[1].strip())
print(fLinesList[2].strip())
print(fLinesList[3].strip())
print(fLinesList[4].strip())
print(fLinesList[5].strip())

wordsInLine4 = fLinesList[4].split()
print('-' * 30, "\nwords in line4  =", wordsInLine4)
QualityPointsprevious=float(wordsInLine4[6])
HoursAttemptedprevious=float(wordsInLine4[2])
GPAprevious=format(QualityPointsprevious/HoursAttemptedprevious,'.2f')

wordsInLine5 = fLinesList[5].split()
print('-' * 30, "\nwords in line5  =", wordsInLine5)

QualityPointsnow=float(wordsInLine5[6])
HoursAttemptednow=int(wordsInLine5[2])
GPAnow=format(QualityPointsnow/HoursAttemptednow,'.2f')
if (OverallHoursAttempted==0,OverallQualityPoints!=0):
    OverallGPA==-1
else:
    if (OverallHoursAttempted==0,OverallQualityPoints==0):
        OverallGPA==0
    else:
        if (GPAprevious==-1):
            OverallGPA==-1
OverallQualityPoints=QualityPointsprevious+QualityPointsnow
OverallHoursAttempted=HoursAttemptedprevious+HoursAttemptednow
OverallGPA=format(OverallQualityPoints/OverallHoursAttempted,'.2f')
QualityPointsprevious=str(QualityPointsprevious)
HoursAttemptedprevious=str(HoursAttemptedprevious)
QualityPointsnow=str(QualityPointsnow)
HoursAttemptednow=str(HoursAttemptednow)



save_path='C:\\TEMP\\'

text1=fLinesList[0]
text2=fLinesList[1]
text3=fLinesList[2]
text4=fLinesList[3]

text5=fLinesList[4]
text51=fLinesList[5]
text6="\n---------------------------"
text7="\nPrevious GPA:\t"+GPAprevious
text8="\nCurrent GPA:\t"+GPAnow
text9="\nOverall GPA:\t"+OverallGPA

text1=str(text1)
text2=str(text2)
text3=str(text3)
text4=str(text4)
text5=str(text5)
text51=str(text51)
text6=str(text6)
text7=str(text7)
text8=str(text8)
text9=str(text9)

wordsInLine0 = fLinesList[0].split()
print('-' * 30, "\nwords in line0  =", wordsInLine0)

lnameofstudent=wordsInLine0[2]
fnameofstudent=wordsInLine0[1]

lnameofstudent=str(wordsInLine0[2])
fnameofstudent=str(wordsInLine0[1])

name=fnameofstudent+" "+lnameofstudent

saveFile=open("C://TEMP//"+name+".txt","w")

saveFile.write(text1)
saveFile.write(text2)
saveFile.write(text3)
saveFile.write(text4)
saveFile.write(text5)
saveFile.write(text51)
saveFile.write(text6)
saveFile.write(text7)
saveFile.write(text8)
saveFile.write(text9)
saveFile.close()
```

Comment: Can you make a summary of the feature you want to implement and reduce the line of code. It's hard to look at your whole code. Thanks.

Comment: This is not `pasteyourhomework.com` !!

Comment: You can read about errors and exceptions here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Pro-tip: when posting a homework problem or data files, post them in text. Homework problems and data files are in text, and text is more compatible with screen-readers, clipboards and search engines, and so pasting them in the most appropriate format will allow readers to help you more easily. If you have to re-type these things from a printed page, then that's what you must do.

Comment: Pro-tip: when asking questions, choose a useful title. "Please help me with my homework" is not very useful, and is primarily made up of pleading, which may discourage readers from helping you. I have improved it based on the question you have asked, but I am not sure that "exceptions" is the key thing here, unless that is an explicit direction from your teacher.

Comment: Ah, when you say "exception", I think you don't mean what readers think you mean. You mean a "special case". In Computer Science, an **exception** is a trappable error that, if not handled, will cause your program to stop. You probably don't need these.

Comment: @omijn: I think the word "exception" was misleading - I have edited it. See the homework text for what was meant. I fell into that trap too `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read your code, on the account of it being too long, and was confused by what you wanted, on the account of it being non-descriptive (no offense). But you ask "How am I suppose to make an exception?" You can make a custom exception with `Exception` as your superclass (is this the correct terminology?). Look at this for an example:

```
class MyError(Exception): #exception names usually end with 'Error'
    pass
```

This should be the way to start making a custom exception, and you can learn more later. Hope this helps slightly.

**EDIT**:
Remember not to create any custom exceptions that have a similar built-in exception, such as `ZeroDivisionError`.